# EXCEPTION: 15dbwrapper_error

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, raspberry-pi, leveldb

I'm running Bitcoind 0.17 on a raspberry Pi 3. Everything ran smoothly until I did something wrong (I guess) but can't figure out what happened. Now I got this error. Has someone experience with this one:

2

```
018-11-23T13:11:47Z Fatal LevelDB error: IO error: /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/indexes/txindex/105794.ldb: Bad message
2018-11-23T13:11:47Z You can use -debug=leveldb to get more complete diagnostic messages
2018-11-23T13:11:47Z 

************************
EXCEPTION: 15dbwrapper_error       
Fatal LevelDB error: IO error: /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/indexes/txindex/105794.ldb: Bad message       
bitcoin in txindex       

2018-11-23T13:12:48Z
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your database is corrupted. This probably means the RPi overheated, or its storage is crappy.

This is not unusual for RPi class hardware.

To recover, you'll need to reindex.

Comment: Thanks Pieter. I guess I better copy the blocks and chainstate again to my RPi (I still have another full node running), instead of using the function -reindex, as this takes a couple of days?

Comment: @Jeans5 have you tried it yet and is it working? Was wondering if copying the full indexed blocks would work without having to sync it from the beginning. I'm trying to find someone who has the full node database from my place.

Comment: Hi @SanicBoom, no I haven't touched it since. Copying a fully indexed blockchain that's up-to-date works perfectly. I had to do it a couple of times to copy it to my RPi and didn't cause any problems.